# Ros 2 remap services

Tags: ros, ros2, service, namespace, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is there (already) a way in Ros 2 to remap services in a launch file?
For example: If my service is on '/service' and my client-node is in a namespace called 'a' and therefore tries to connect to '/a/service'.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323052/ros-2-remap-services/) by [.zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/40609/.zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2019-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes:

https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Node-arguments/#name-remapping

https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/9a6ed82b4eb75226937b2709da1071c6f05a3750/launch_ros/launch_ros/actions/node.py#L120-L121

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2019-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0